# Datagridview average of selected cells

Tags: datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I have a simple windows forms datagridview .Which event can be used to get data of selected cells? I can select multiple cells at a time and would like of display average of the values in cells selected. The selected cells will be in order.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for the SelectionChanged event...

```
private void DataGridView1SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int avg = 0;
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        int val;
        int.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out val);
        avg += val;
    }

    // prevent division by zero
    if(dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 0)
        label.Text = (avg/dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count).ToString();
}
```

Note: if there's a value that can not be parsed it will still be counted as divisor.

Comment: I guess this doesn't work for Mouse click selection of multiple cells and I am not able to select multiple cells at once .Any time I just click a cell in this Grid ,the event gets fired

Comment: have a look at the `DataGridView.MultiSelect` property. and of course, whenever you select a cell the events gets fired.